# Using Socket to connect to Server in Pc from mobile

Tags: android

I wrote an app to connect to java server running in PC. It works fine in emulator but its not working when i try the same from my mobile. I used the Mobiles 3G network to connect to IP address.

Comment: What happens? What's the error? Which IPs do you use? Consider that the Emulator is running on the same machine as the server (probably). The device with 3G has to connect trough your router which should forward your request to the server.

Comment: the pblm is i am not connecting at all. the server receives no connection.So shld i add somethng extra if i have to use the app from mobile.

Answer (score 1):

(Based on question comment)

I assume that your server application is running on the same machine as the android emulator. In this case the emulator can reach your server with `10.0.2.2`.

If you're trying to contact your server via mobile 3G you have to use the IP of your Internet connection ([What is my IP?](http://www.whatismyip.com/)). The request will reach your router. The router has to forward this request to your server machine. So if your server has a local IP `192.168.0.10` and it listens to port `2412` your router should forward all incoming request for this TCP port to this IP.

Answer (score 0):

You should allow the 3G internet in Settings. (Emulator doesn't need this, it uses ethernet connection of your PC).

Your application should diagnose the state and possibilities of Internet connection and report it to you as a user of the debug mode. Or/and something - to the usual user.

Comment: Wht settings are u talkin abt..I ll try to diagnose connection from app..thnks